# server.getWorld(String) always returning null? Bukkit API

Tags: java, bukkit

I am trying to use the method `getWorld` to get the world of a string, but every time, no matter what string I input, `null` is returned. Here is an example of what I have tried:

`World world = server.getWorld("world");`

As documented [here](http://jd.bukkit.org/rb/doxygen/d4/da9/interfaceorg_1_1bukkit_1_1Server.html#a95b1968f5cc6d405e054606f7b403cec) it states that the method would return null if the world does not exist, however I have made sure that my world name is `world`. I've googled around too for a solution, but no luck.

Comment: Your code looks great! Maybe its an issue with Bukkit API, or perhaps you are building for a version other than 1.6.4-R2? This is all i can think of at the moment, except maybe its case sensitive.

Comment: Try using the `getWorlds()` method to see all available worlds. There is a chance that it's in the wrong directory maybe.

Comment: @Drifter64 Thanks! I am using the latest recommended build for 1.6.4 so there shouldn't be any problems there. I Suppose I'll fill out a bug report unless someone else thinks I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: @Obicere that method does work for me and I can see a list of loaded worlds with it, which opens up a viable temporary solution until this is fixed. I'll probably write my own method to check against the `World`s in that list. Thanks for the input.

Comment: @Alex so that's definitely a bug in the client. Then again, it might have something to do with the word choice for the name, I truly don't know. Hopefully this gets resolved soon :)

Comment: For anyone else looking `getWorlds()[0]` will usually return your default world, though `Bukkit.getWorld(worldName)` is preferable.  
Alternatively, get the world from a player instance using `player.getWorld()` if you know the player is in that world.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `getServer().getWorld()`, it will return null every time. You need to get it from Bukkit itself. It's in the API twice, but only one is working. use `Bukkit.getWorld()` and it will work just fine.

Comment: I don't think that would make a difference, since it doesn't return `null` for me every time. Do you have any references to back up your claim?